# Showing $f$ has atleast one root in $|z|<1$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is analytic in $|z|<6/5$, $f(0)=1$ and $|f(z)|\geq 2$ when $|z|=1$. Show that $f$ has atleast one root in $|z|<1$. I have no idea how to solve this, All i am thinking at this moment is to consider $1/f$ in $|z|<1$ and apply minimum modulus principle. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Your $\frac{1}{f}$ argument does work. If $f$ doesn't have a root in $|z| < 1$, then $\frac{1}{f}$ is analytic over $|z| < 1 + \epsilon$. You then have $|\frac{1}{f(0)}| = 1 > \frac12 \ge |\frac{1}{f(z)}|$ for all $|z| = 1$. Contradicting the maximum modulus principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take Rouches Theorem with $g(z)=-1$ obviously $|g(z)|< |f(z)|$ for all $z$ with $|z|=1$ and $f+g$ does surely have one zero in $|z|<1$.